# Extract JS array string in VBS

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm coding in VBSscript.

I have the following string

```
myString = "[ "http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com" ]
```

How can I extract the urls with regexp? is there anyway to read this JS array?

Comment: I agree with Bartdude, it seems to be the best route and simple too, using the SPLIT function will return an array of elements too, and will work on any number of elements (within reason). I would have posted the SAME solution as BArtdude and as he has done so already, there seems no point in re-iterating what he has stated.

Answer (score 2):

I would remove starting and trailing brackets, then use the split method. I don't think regex are intended to do that...

Answer (score 0):

RegExp for easy cases (no embeded "):

```
  ' Mark the correct quotes
  Dim sTest : sTest = "[ ""http://www.google.com/"", ""http://www.yahoo.com"", """" ]"
  WScript.Echo sTest
  Dim reStringLiteral : Set reStringLiteral = New RegExp
  reStringLiteral.Global  = True
  reStringLiteral.Pattern = """([^""]*)"""
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reStringLiteral.Execute(sTest)
  Dim oMT
  For Each oMT In oMTS
      WScript.Echo oMT.Value, oMT.SubMatches(0)
  Next
```

output:

```
[ "http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com", "" ]
"http://www.google.com/" http://www.google.com/
"http://www.yahoo.com" http://www.yahoo.com
""
```

Split() for easy cases (invariant ", " separator):

```
  Dim sTest : sTest = "[ ""http://www.google.com/"", ""http://www.yahoo.com"", """" ]"
  WScript.Echo sTest
  Dim reNetto : Set reNetto = New RegExp
  reNetto.Global  = True
  reNetto.Pattern = "^[^""]*""|""[^""]*$"
  sTest = reNetto.Replace(sTest, "")
  WScript.Echo sTest
  Dim sUrl
  For Each sUrl In Split(sTest, """, """)
      WScript.Echo qq(sUrl), sUrl
  Next
```

output:

```
[ "http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com", "" ]
http://www.google.com/", "http://www.yahoo.com", "
"http://www.google.com/" http://www.google.com/
"http://www.yahoo.com" http://www.yahoo.com
""
```